# Why is \textsc having no effect here?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

1st case ("microtype"): `\textsc` yielding no effect, but rest of that left columnn is nicely aligned (notice the dates are "flush"):

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{gitinfo}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\pdfprotrudechars=2
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}

\setmainfont[Microtype, Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri}
 \newfontface\NoMicrotype[Numbers={OldStyle}, Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri}



\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79414/how-to-align-the-following-in-a-table
\usepackage{calc}
%%%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79414/how-to-align-the-following-in-a-table

% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{array}

%%%-------------------------------------

\usepackage{colortbl}
 \newlength{\mycustomlength}


\settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}    
\usepackage{tabularx}


%%% tex.SX (97180) - How to get column alignment in tabularx?
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}



\begin{document}

%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\NoMicrotype}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}} % sub-headings modification
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}} % sub-headings modification
%%%

\strut\rlap{\textsc{\color{blue}Some Subtitle}}%
  \raisebox{-.7mm}
  {%
    \noindent\tikz\shade[left color=blue, right color=white, middle color=white] 
    (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,-0.02);
  } 
  \\ 
%%%%%%
blaaaaaaaaa & blaaaaaaaaaaa.
\\
& blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\\
01/1803\,–\,04/1901 & blaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaa
\\
12/1815\,–\,07/1899 & blaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaa
\\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

---

2nd case ("no microtype"): `\textsc` **works**, but rest of that columnn is ***not*** nicely aligned (dates are *not* "flush"):

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{gitinfo}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\pdfprotrudechars=2
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}

\setmainfont[Microtype, Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri}
 \newfontface\NoMicrotype[Numbers={OldStyle}, Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri}



\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79414/how-to-align-the-following-in-a-table
\usepackage{calc}
%%%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79414/how-to-align-the-following-in-a-table

% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{array}

%%%-------------------------------------

\usepackage{colortbl}
 \newlength{\mycustomlength}


\settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}    
\usepackage{tabularx}


%%% tex.SX (97180) - How to get column alignment in tabularx?
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}



\begin{document}

%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\NoMicrotype}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}} % sub-headings modification
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}} % sub-headings modification
%%%

\strut\rlap{\textsc{\color{blue}Some Subtitle}}%
  \raisebox{-.7mm}
  {%
    \noindent\tikz\shade[left color=blue, right color=white, middle color=white] 
    (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,-0.02);
  } 
  \\ 
%%%%%%
blaaaaaaaaa & blaaaaaaaaaaa.
\\
& blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\\
01/1803\,–\,04/1901 & blaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaa
\\
12/1815\,–\,07/1899 & blaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaa
\\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

---

Any way to override the column's `\NoMicrotype` (which seems responsible for defecting `\textsc`) setting for the "Some Subtitle" line (row, cell, whatever) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unrelated to `microtype` or `tabularx`, you specified proportional figures so the digits have different widths, just omit that and you do not need to load two fonts.

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{gitinfo}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\protrudechars=2
\adjustspacing=2
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}

\setmainfont[Microtype, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Calibri}




\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79414/how-to-align-the-following-in-a-table
\usepackage{calc}
%%%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79414/how-to-align-the-following-in-a-table

% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{array}

%%%-------------------------------------

\usepackage{colortbl}
 \newlength{\mycustomlength}


\settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}    
\usepackage{tabularx}


%%% tex.SX (97180) - How to get column alignment in tabularx?
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}



\begin{document}

%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\NoMicrotype}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}} % sub-headings modification
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}} % sub-headings modification
%%%

\strut\rlap{\textsc{\color{blue}Some Subtitle}}%
  \raisebox{-.7mm}
  {%
    \noindent\tikz\shade[left color=blue, right color=white, middle color=white] 
    (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,-0.02);
  } 
  \\ 
%%%%%%
blaaaaaaaaa & blaaaaaaaaaaa.
\\
& blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\\
01/1803\,–\,04/1901 & blaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaa
\\
12/1815\,–\,07/1899 & blaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaablaaaaa blaaaa
\\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Note this page has unusably over full boxes but I left that for now:

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
Overfull \hbox (263.07129pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 75--75
[]||[][]| 

Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 75--76
```

Comment: almost there: chucking out "proportional" did the trick, but a different table with `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{\mycustomlength}Xc@{}}` ended up misaligned. Any quick-n-dirty trick to keep "proportional" for this other table?

Comment: the alignment is like "justified" and the words spread out with a linebreak. I'd like to keep them nicely together like in the text of this comment.

Comment: for that offending line I now just "glued" the words together with a tilde `~` which is satisfactory.